# Create variables in jsf without outputting the value

Tags: jsp, jsf, el

In jsp i can create custom variables using el like in this case

```
#{l = ["one", "two", "three"]}
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="#{l}"/>
</h:body>
```

But in this case as soon as i create them in the first line they get outputted on the page result in a double. Is there a way to define them without printing them on the screen ?

Comment: Using jsp with jsf has been deprecated for several years now. Are you sure you are using jsp?

Comment: Sorry, i meant jsf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JSTL set tag as described here [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm%20JSTL%20%3Cset%3E) 
Which would look like:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
    <head>
    <title><c:set> Tag Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
        <c:out value="${salary}"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is also possible to use standard JSP scriptlets to embed Java code and declare variables that are available throughout the JSP and can be used in EL:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <%
        // This is a scriptlet.  Notice that the "date"
        // variable we declare here is available in the
        // embedded expression later on.
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    %>
        The time is now <%= date %>
    </body>
</html>
```